# R loop question- looping through a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop

I am new to R and need some help figuring out a problem.
In summary, I have a dataframe with different values : 10 rows and 6 columns. Each column represents a variable: column 1- n1, column2- mean1, column3- varaince1, column4- n2, column5- mean2, column6- variance2. Each row is a different combination of these variables.
I want to iterate through each row and generate two samples- sample 1- random normal variables with n1,mean1 and sd1 (variance1 sqrt) and sample 2-random normal variables with n1,mean1 and sd1 (variance1 sqrt).
Can someone let me know what would be the best way to proceed? Thanks for the help.

Here is a sample data I have using the dput() function:

```
structure(list(n1 = c(5, 10, 5, 10, 5, 10), n2 = c(3, 3, 6, 6, 
3, 3), mean1 = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6), mean2 = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 
15, 15), sd1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), sd2 = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10)), out.attrs = list(dim = c(n1 = 2L, n2 = 2L, mean1 = 2L, 
mean2 = 2L, sd1 = 2L, sd2 = 2L), dimnames = list(n1 = c("n1= 5", 
"n1=10"), n2 = c("n2=3", "n2=6"), mean1 = c("mean1=4", "mean1=6"
), mean2 = c("mean2=15", "mean2=20"), sd1 = c("sd1=1", "sd1=5"
), sd2 = c("sd2=10", "sd2= 4"))), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You have `n2` listed for column2 and column4. Give us a sample of the data to work with, e.g. 5-6 rows of the data using `dput(head(yourdata))` and paste the results into your question. It will substantially improve your chances of getting a quick, useful answer.

Comment: Thank you @dcarlson. Updated my question with sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the data generated in lists. *params* is the data frame of parameters.

```
data1<-list()
data2<-list()
for(i in 1:dim(params)[1]){
  data_1i<- rnorm(n= params$n1[i], mean= params$mean1[i], sd=params$sd1[i] )
  data_2i<- rnorm(n= params$n2[i], mean= params$mean2[i], sd=params$sd2[i] )

  data1[[i]]<- data_1i
  data2[[i]]<- data_2i
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Constanza Zepeda. It works. Not sure why but in the beginning it gave me an error "object of the type 'closure' is not subsettable'. Now it works though.

Answer (score 1):

You did not indicate how you plan to use the results. This will store both sets of random numbers in a list:

```
set.seed(42)   # For reproducibility
results <- apply(params, 1, function(x) list(first=rnorm(x[1], x[3], x[5]),
           second=rnorm(x[2], x[4], x[6])))
    results[[1]]
    # $first
    # [1] 5.370958 3.435302 4.363128 4.632863 4.404268
    # 
    # $second
    # [1] 13.93875 30.11522 14.05341
    # 
    results[[1]]$first
    # [1] 5.370958 3.435302 4.363128 4.632863 4.404268
    results[[1]]$second
    # [1] 13.93875 30.11522 14.05341
```

If you want to use these to compute a t-test, then you can do that directly without storing the randomly generated values:

```
set.seed(42)
results.t <- apply(params, 1, function(x) t.test(rnorm(x[1], x[3], x[5]), 
             rnorm(x[2], x[4], x[6])))
results.t[[1]]
# 
#   Welch Two Sample t-test
# 
# data:  rnorm(x[1], x[3], x[5]) and rnorm(x[2], x[4], x[6])
# t = -2.7736, df = 2.0133, p-value = 0.1083
# alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  -37.938884   8.083236
# sample estimates:
# mean of x mean of y 
#  4.441304 19.369128
```

Or you can use `results`:

```
 results.t2 <- lapply(results, function(x) t.test(x$first, x$second))
results.t2[[1]]
# 
#   Welch Two Sample t-test
# 
# data:  x$first and x$second
# t = -2.7736, df = 2.0133, p-value = 0.1083
# alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#  95 percent confidence interval:
#  -37.938884   8.083236
# sample estimates:
# mean of x mean of y 
#  4.441304 19.369128
```

Answer (score 1):

A `purrr` way:

```
 library(purrr) 
 library(dplyr)
  df %>% 
    group_nest(row_number()) %>% 
    pull(data) %>% 
    map(~.x %>% tibble(first = rnorm(n = n1, mean = mean1, sd = sd1),
                       second = rnorm(n = n2, mean = mean2, sd = sd2)) %>% 
          select(first, second)) 
  # if you want them in one df: bind_rows()
```

Comment: Thank you @Julian for the help. I think I should learn more about the purrr library, code looks way cleaner.